# update textview in fragment every 1 second

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to update a textview in a fragment every 1 second.It is crashing after 1 second. Any help. 
" android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

```
   doAsync {
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(1000, 1000)
      { timing_of_task.text = (Date() - task!!.tasktimer!!.startTime).formatted() }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use AsyncTask to alter UI elements!

Use a `TimerTask`

Comment: timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                            override fun run() {
                               activity!!.runOnUiThread {
          
               timing_of_task.text = (Date() - task!!.tasktimer!!.startTime).formatted()
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1000, 1000)